# add new row conditionally xslt

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have the following XML:

```
<table class="DETAILGROUP" UID="2001">
  <row class="FIGURE">
    <cell class="FIGURE">figure</cell>
  </row>
  <row class="DETAILLINE">
    <cell class="CALLOUT">22</cell>
    <cell class="SPECIALMATERIAL">Support</cell>
    <cell class="PARTNUMBER">SRM</cell>
  </row>
  <row class="DETAILLINE">
    <cell class="CALLOUT">33</cell>
    <cell class="SPECIALMATERIAL">Machine</cell>
    <cell class="PARTNUMBER"></cell>
  </row>
  <row class="DETAILLINE">
    <cell class="CALLOUT">Support</cell>
    <cell class="SPECIALMATERIAL"></cell>
    <cell class="PARTNUMBER"></cell>
  </row>
</table>
```

In output HTML I need to hide the PARTNUMBER column, only if the above Table element has any column with "SPECIALMATERIAL" as its Class attribute; Secondly, I need to insert a new row just after the"figure" tag row. In this case new row should come at 2nd position.So, Final HTML will be like this-

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                figure
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Sr
            </td>
            <td>
                Name
            </td>
            <td>
                Description
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                22
            </td>
            <td>
                Support
            </td>
            <td>
                SRM
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                33
            </td>
            <td>
                Machine
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: You have to learn to accept answers for your previous questions if you want to get them for new ones.

Comment: Also, show what you have tried - users are unlikely to do the task for you, but likely to help you fix what you've got.